# What's the purpose of null in X >: Null <: Y?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
abstract type
ClassSymbol >: Null <: Universe.TypeSymbol with Universe.ClassSymbolApi
```

This was found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Universe@ClassSymbol%3E:Null%3C:Symbols.this.TypeSymbolwithSymbols.this.ClassSymbolApi).  I realize there is a description of what this does, but I can't make sense of it from a syntax standpoint.

What's the purpose of Null?  It looks like it might be some kind of default but I only surmise that because I only see this kind of syntax with types, and I think null can be something returns for type without your program breaking.  this is an abstract type, but it doesn't have a parameter which you can specify later, so how does this work as an abstract type?

Comment: `Null` is a type: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null

Comment: Indeed it is, but how can it have a specific type and also be an abstract type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Null` is a type that specifies that something can be `null`.  It's not a supertype, strictly speaking, because you can't do *anything* with a `null` except pass it around and check that, yep, it's still `null`.  In this way it's very much like `Nothing`, except that you can't even get an instance of a `Nothing` to pass around.

Now, one could say, "well, any `AnyRef` could be `null`", but then how do you think of the instance `null` itself?  `null` can fill in for pretty much anything, which, as a type, means that it must be a *subtype* of everything that can be `null`!  And that's what `Null` is: the subtype of everything that can be `Null`.

Wait, wait, you say.  You can't *actually* have a subtype of everything--that means that `null` would have every possible functionality!  If you think about it, `null` *does* promise every type of functionality that any `AnyRef` has--but they're all empty promises, and whenever you try to use that functionality you get a `NullPointerException` instead.

Now, the question is, why make a type `>: Null` (meaning that `null` is a valid value for it) instead of `<: AnyRef` which should imply the same thing?

Well, it turns out that Scala doesn't actually model things that way, to leave open the possibility that you could have an `AnyRef` which you were absolutely sure could not ever possibly be `null`.  So asking for `<: AnyRef` ("I am a subclass of AnyRef") doesn't mean the same thing theoretically, even though in practice absolutely-not-null-`AnyRef`s are not really implemented.  (Also, `Any` would get really awkward if `Null` was not an explicit type.)

So `type Foo >: Null <: Bar` just means that you explicitly admit that `null` can fill in for instances of any possible type of `Foo`, and thus you can write `val foo: Foo = null`.

Comment: Your answer is good but not that succinct :)  And, yes, I believe that A <: AnyRef is different from A >: Null because of the type Nothing.

Comment: @nicky_zs - It seemed to me that it might require some length to get the point across.  However, one could perfectly well have the lower bound of `Null` implicit in `AnyRef`, as Java does with `null` and `Object`; `Nothing` doesn't really make a difference.  `Any` does, however: an `Any` is allowed to contain `null` but may contain values whose more precise types do not admit `null`.

Comment: in fact my point is that `type T >: Null; val x: T = null` is OK while `type T <: AnyRef; val x: T = null` will fail due to the error of "type mismatch".

Comment: @nicky_zs - True, but that's because `Any` is a superclass of `AnyRef` (and `AnyVal`s _can't_ be null.)

Comment: I don't think `type T <: AnyRef;` has anything related to `AnyVal` because `type T` is already bounded upto AnyRef. Althought `Any` is a superclass of `AnyRef`, `T` can't be `Any` nor be `AnyVal`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
trait Foo {
  type A >: Null
  def someA: A = null
}
```

In the above dummy trait, `A` is an abstract type member with a type bound. This means: Whatever a subclass defines `A` to be, `Null` must be a subtype of it. (The opposite is also possible: `A <: Bar`).

The main reason for doing is, is to make `null` be a valid value for `A` as can be seen in the second line. Without it, scalac would complain at the second line:

```
found   : Null(null)
required: Foo.this.A
```

To your question what `Null` is: It's the type of `null` and it is a subtype of `AnyRef` and all of its subtypes.